# Can the user visit the profile page without signing in?

Tags: php, session

The code of login page

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost" , "root" , "");
mysqli_select_db($connect , "mysqli");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect , $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect , $_POST['password']);
    if($username and $password){


    $query = mysqli_query($connect , "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '$username' AND password LIKE '$password'");
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($check > 0){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        echo "<script>window.open('profile.php' , '_self')</script>";
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('Wrong username or password')</script>";
    }
    }
    else{
        echo "<script>alert('Please enter all fields')</script>";
    }
}


?>
```

the code of profile page

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['username'] or $_SESSION['password']){
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

?>

<marquee><font size="20">Welcome To A.S Service <?php echo "" . $_SESSION['username'];?> :)</font></marquee>
<?php
}
else{
    header("header:main.php?notify=Oops Something Went Wrong!!!");
}
?>
```

The code of logout process

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['username'] or $_SESSION['password']){
    session_destroy();
    header("location:main.php?notify=Now You're Logged Out");
}
```

I made a login form...but I'm confused of something..The profile page of the user is a normal page named by "profile.php"...so when I publish my website on the internet I don't want him to visit the profile page by the domain(url) without signing in...So does my code protect it and keep it secured?!...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have invalid argument near `header:main.php`.

Change from

```
header("header:main.php?notify=Oops Something Went Wrong!!!");
```

To

```
header("location:main.php?notify=Oops Something Went Wrong!!!");
```

> or

Add check in your `profile.php` by using following example code

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['username'] == null)
{
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Why you are storing `password` in session?

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
```

It is better to store `username` or `userid` in session, instead of storing password.

Comment: So..that's the only problem...then everything goes ok ?

Comment: Sorry what about userid which comes instead of password ?

Comment: @AhmedSaieed Please donot store password into session as you are doing in your file `login.php`

Comment: Now after editing.....

profile.php

   <?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['username'] or $_SESSION['password']){
 $username = $_SESSION['username'];

?>

<marquee><font size="20">Welcome To A.S Service <?php echo "" . $_SESSION['username'];?> :)</font></marquee>
<?php
}
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) or $_SESSION['username'] == null){
 header("location: main.php");
}
?>

main.php

Removed the stored SESSION password..now only the username stored.

is it ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Not unless there's something in your profile.php file itself that checks whether the user is authenticated, and forces a redirect if he isn't.

Best way to secure your site would be to include an auth check at the beginning of each php file that requires authorization to view. Otherwise, a malicious user could theoretically request the page (or script, or portion of your template, etc.) directly (i.e. type in the URL instead of following a link) and view any page he likes.

Better yet: write a single php script that checks auth, and `include` wherever necessary. For example:

```
<?php

session_start();
if (!$_SESSION['username']) {
    header('Location:login.php');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue with that code is actually `header("header:main.php?notify=Oops Something Went Wrong!!!");` which should be `header("Location: main.php?notify=Oops Something Went Wrong!!!");` - notice the word `Location` and the space between `:` and the hyperlink.

As for your code itself, you have the right idea - the act of **logging in** generates a **token** in the `$_SESSION`, such as the `username` credential, and `all` pages subsequently start the page with `session_start()` and immediately check for the presence of the token, or else **redirect the user**.

I would recommend having this code snippet at the top of the page - don't wrap your HTML inside PHP like you've done, as it will become unmanageable very quickly:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['username'] or !$_SESSION['password']){ 
    header("Location: main.php?notify=Oops Something Went Wrong!!!");
}
?>
```

Comment: So..you recommend using this code instead of my code in profile.php ?

Comment: @AhmedSaieed I recommend that code which checks for user logins should be placed at the very top of your `.php` file. The HTML content should be placed after that initial block of PHP code - this is generally considered 'good practice'.